# Function with all derivative at $0$ is $1$ .

Tags: calculus

Give an example of an indefinitely differentiable function on real line other than exponential function such that its all derivatives at $0$ is $1$ ?

Comment: Do you already know a function that is infinitely differentiable and has all derivatives $0$ in $0$ without being identically $0$?

Comment: yeah that i know and then you will say add these two function. function that you are talking about is this $f(x)$ is $0$ on $x \leq 0$  and $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ on $x \geq 0$.

Comment: But can you seggest better example?

Comment: That's one of the possibilities, there are many. But if $f^{(k)}(0) = 1$ for all $k$, then $g(x) = e^x-f(x)$ gives you a function with $g^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for all $k$, so that is the only [you can cloth it in different guises, however] way to obtain a function with the desired properties.

Answer (score 4):

There are functions on the real line (other than 0) with the property that all derivatives at 0 are 0.

Add this function to the exp-function and youre done.

Comment: can you suggest better than this example.

Comment: No, there is no better example since every example is exactly of this form. If you have a function with your required property and you subtract the exponential function you get a function with all derivatives at 0 are 0.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The function $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{z^2}}$, all its derivates are $0$ at $0$.